# PHP Shorten the condition

Tags: php

Can you help me shorten this condition?

```
$is_plugins_page = isset( $_GET['page'] ) && $_GET['page'] == 'page1' || $_GET['page'] == 'mypag2plugin' || $_GET['page'] == 'homepluginpage';
```

> Nested bets

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$is_plugins_page = isset($_GET['page']) && in_array($_GET['page'], ['page1', 'mypag2plugin', 'homepluginpage']);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = [
        'page1',
        'mypag2plugin',
        'homepluginpage'
    ];
$is_plugins_page = isset( $_GET['page'] ) && in_array($_GET['page'], $arr);
```

Comment: Hello, please explain your answer.